# Is there any option for making a horizontal line in listview?

Tags: java, android

I am using a listview and i need to group items showing as a group.
So i need a separator to separate the listitems of the same list.

But i need this separator to set dynamically(means through java code)

Comment: you should have done google before posting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there a Seperators by default, a great Tutorial how to group a Listview can be found here: http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=440

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line in your listview tag of XML file

android:divider="@drawable/line"
where line is image of a line..or you can also use a color code instead of  "@drawable/line"

Comment: he hasn't for mentioned for separating listview item, but for separating groups by providing group separator.

Answer (score 0):

in your list item xml file put the code:

```
 <View android:id="@+id/line"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:background="@color/pink"/>
```